# How can I infer the type of the method on Java dynamically?

Tags: java, generics

I have this two classes, using generics:

```
public Response version1(Parameters params) {
   Supplier<Response> s = () -> getResponse(params);
   return unversioned(params, s);
}

public Response2 version2(Parameters params) {
   Supplier<Response2> s = () -> getResponse2(params);
   // s.get().getData(); Here, I am able to get the Data, because it knows it's from a Response2 class.
   return unversioned(params, s);
}
```

These two generics are used for me to not have to duplicate every single line of code, as the methods are pretty much the same, just one line of code is different, which is the return type.
So, when I call the generics:

```
private <T> T unversioned(Parameters parameters, Supplier<T> supplier) {
    T result = supplier.get();
}
```

When I try to get the `result.getData()` method, it does not understand. Because it does not infer the type. How can I do that?

Comment: could you please format the code and give full (simplified) snippets. it's hard to get what is going on and how you use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is add bounds to the generic type of your `unversioned` method.

```java
private <T extends DataProvider> T unversioned(Parameters parameters, Supplier<T> supplier) {
  // logic
}
```

This, however, requires you to have your response objects implement an interface:

```java
public interface DataProvider {
  /*
   * Not sure what the return type of getData is, so used String for illustrative purposes
   */
  String getData(); 
}
```

In case your response objects need to have different return values for `getData` you could further generify the interface.

```java
public interface DataProvider<T> {
  T getData(); 
}
```

This requires a slight tweak of the `unversioned` method:

```java
private <T extends DataProvider<?>> T unversioned(Parameters parameters, Supplier<T> supplier) {
  // logic
}
```

And you can now define your response objects as follows:

```java
public class StringResponse implements DataProvider<String> {
  @Override
  public String getData() {
    // logic
  }
}

public class IntegerResponse implements DataProvider<Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer getData() {
    // logic
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, but, for example, getData returns a different type for each one of the classes, how could this be done? Because, then, I would have to infer the type of getData too.

Comment: You could add generics to `IDataProvider`. I will edit my answer to illustrate

Comment: This makes so much sense! Thanks a lot, Jeroen! Just one more thing, when I add extends to unversioned method, and calls it. It gives me this error: ```reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Response2 conforms to ResponseDataProvider```, saying that the required type is Supplier<T>. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Does Response2 implement the interface?